# indexing partial data - i think

Tags: indexing, match, partial

I have an "expenses" spreadsheet, an "income" spreadsheet and a "Shipping Account" spreadsheet.

In the 'expenses' spreadsheet:

- Column B3:B200 contains descriptive text which is selected from a dropdown menu using Data validation. This contains 3 different descriptions that all start with the word shipping (i.e. Shipping: Aust Post; Shipping: E-Fees & shipping: other fees)
- Column A3:A:200 contains the date
- Column J3:J200 contains the $$ spent (e.g. $20)

The 'income' spreadsheet has:

- the date in column A3:A200, and
- the amount paid by customer in column G3:G200

I want the 'shipping account' spreadsheet to automatically update to to reflect all shipping related transactions. In the 'shipping account' spreadsheet the following zones have the following data:

- A3:A200 (date)
- B3:B200 (shipping $ received)
- C3:C200 (shipping expenses)

When a description (B3:B200) in the 'expenses' spreadsheet begins with "Shipping" I want:

- The Column C value in 'shipping account' updated with the Column J value from 'expenses'
- The Column A (date) value in 'shipping account' updated with the Column A (date) value from 'expenses'.

When the `income` spreadsheet is updated I want:

- The Column B value in 'shipping account' updated with the Column G value in 'income'
- The Column A (date) value in 'shipping account' updated with the Column A (date) value from 'income'.

I've tried

```
=INDEX(J3:J200,MATCH("shipping",B3:B200,1))
=INDEX(J3:J200,MATCH((LEFT(Shipping,8),B3:B200,1)) 
=(INDEX(Expenses!J3:J200,MATCH(D8,Expenses!B3:B200,1)))
```

D8 just containing the word shipping

```
=INDEX(J3:J200,MATCH("*"&shipping&"*", B3:B200, 0)
=INDEXJ3:J200(B:B;MATCH("Shipping";B:B;0))
```

Comment: i'm now looking in a different direction and trying to combine index and aggregate.  I seem to be progressing better BUT ....  i'm using the row function to manipulate the aggregate array.  overall the formula is working, technically but it't not recognising what i need it to as true- everything comes back false-  i should have a true response in positions 2, 4, 8 but it's not happening:  the portion of the formula for this is:                                                                            AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Expenses!$A$3:$A$200)-1/(Expenses!$B$3:$B$200="Shipping*"))

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated, i thought this would be simple and now 2 days later i'm tearing my hair out-  yes i am a novice at this

Comment: AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Expenses!$A$3:$A$200)-ROW(Expenses!$A$3)+1/(Expenses!$B$3:$B$200="Shipping*"),ROWS(Expenses!B$3:B3))

Comment: AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Expenses!$A$3:$A$200)-ROW(Expenses!$A$3)+1/(Expenses!$B$3:$B$200="Shipping*"),ROWS(Expenses!B$3:B3))      is only returning errors - am so lost - thought this would be simple